# Can't retrieve info from xml document with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm starting to learn xml and xsl, but for some reason I can't make the xpath work for me in xsl. Is my xml document structured in a wrong way or why isn't the price of game 14 displayed in the table?

My xsl attempt is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My Games</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Game Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select=
            "Xboxspellen/Spellen/Spel[14]/Spelnaam"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select=
            "Xboxspellen/Spellen/Spel[14]/Prijs"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Shorter version of xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Xboxspellen.xsl"?>
<Xboxspellen xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com 
                                 Xboxspellen.xsd">
  <Genres>
    ...
    <Genre id="Adv">
      <Genrenaam>Adventure</Genrenaam>
      <Spel idref="12"/>
      <Spel idref="13"/>
      <Spel idref="14"/>
    </Genre>
  </Genres>

  <Spellen>
    ...
    ...
    <Spel id="14">
      <Spelnaam>Omerta: city of gangsters</Spelnaam>
      <Uitgever>Kalypso</Uitgever>
      <Prijs>49.98</Prijs>
      <Leeftijd>16</Leeftijd>
      <Aankoop>
        <Dag>28</Dag>
        <Maand>04</Maand>
        <Jaar>2011</Jaar>
      </Aankoop>
      <Afbeelding>spel14.jpg</Afbeelding>
    </Spel>
  </Spellen>
</Xboxspellen>
```

I've been trying things for hours but don't seem to find the answer, if anyone could help me, I'd be very thankful :D

Comment: You have a default namespace declared in your XML, but not in your XSLT, so they do not match.

Answer (score 1):

Add: `xmlns:w3="http://www.w3schools.com"` to the xsl:stylesheet element.

and add the w3 prefix to the elements in your select statement:

```
    <td><xsl:value-of select=
        "w3:Xboxspellen/w3:Spellen/w3:Spel[@id='14']/w3:Spelnaam"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select=
        "w3:Xboxspellen/w3:Spellen/w3:Spel[@id='14']/w3:Prijs"/></td>
```

Your xml is in the default namespace "http://www.w3schools.com", 
but the xpaths in your xsl select is in the null namespace. 
They don't match. Namespace match is not by prefix ( or lack of prefix )
but by the namespaces that the prefixes  are bound to.

```
{http://www.w3schools.com}/Xboxspellen != {}/Xboxspellen
```

See this for more: [XML Namespaces and How They Affect XPath and XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx)

Also: [The perils of default namespaces](http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/36)

Note: I changed "[14]" to "[@id='14']"  to make it work for your example.
If that element is actually the 14th in the sequence then you don't need
to change that. But if you have id's, then I'ld probably rely on them rather
than counting.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a good start.  And now you've bumped your shins on a classic slip that happens to everyone sooner or later:  You've written an XPath expression like `Xboxspellen/Spellen/Spel[14]/Spelnaam` and expect it to match an element in your document.  But the elements in your document are not named `Xboxspellen`, etc.:  they are namespace-qualified, and all of them have a default namespace declaration (`xmlns="..."`) in scope, so their full (expanded) name is not `Xboxspellen` etc., but `{http://www.w3schools.com}Xboxspellen`, `{http://www.w3schools.com}Spellen`, etc.

Correct the situation by making your XPath expressions and your XML agree on the names of things.  In the usual case, this means:

1. Add a namespace declaration to your XSLT stylesheet, binding some prefix (it doesn't matter what prefix) to the namespace used in your XML:

   xmlns:w3s = "http://www.w3schools.com"
2. Use that prefix in your XPath expressions:

   ```
   <td><xsl:value-of select="w3s:Xboxspellen
                             /w3s:Spellen
                             /w3s:Spel[14]
                             /w3s:Spelnaam" /></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="w3s:Xboxspellen
                             /w3s:Spellen
                             /w3s:Spel[14]
                             /w3s:Prijs"/></td>
   ```

(I've broken lines in the XPath for legibility; white space is legal in XPath expressions, and it's a good thing, too.)

Now the XPath expression will match.